# Can't consume ASP.NET Web Service from jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, web-services, json

Here's an interesting problem:

I have some jQuery that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:63056/Service1.asmx/PrintOrderRecieptXml",
    data: {
      "CouponCode": "TESTCODE",
      "Subtotal": 14.2600,
      "ShippingTotal": 7.5000,
      "TaxTotal": 0.0000,
      "GrandTotal": 21.7600,
      "OrderItemCollection": [{
        "Total": 14.2600,
        "Qty": 250
      }]
    },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    error: function(xhr, msg) {
      alert(xhr.statusText);
    }
  });
});
```

Now, the problem I'm having is that it's sending the request, but the web service isn't processing it correctly. In IE, I get an alert box with "Internal Server Error" and with FireFox I get an alert box with nothing in it.

The strange thing is that when I use IE, I do not get an error event in my event log, but with firefox I get (bonus points for figuring out why this is):

"Exception message: Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/PrintOrderRecieptXml"

I poked around some and found out that sometimes you have to add:

```
<webServices>
  <protocols>
    <add name="HttpGet"/>
    <add name="HttpPost" />
    <add name="HttpPostLocalhost"/>

  </protocols>
</webServices>
```

To your Web.Config, which I did but it did not help. The interesting thing is that the web service works fine with SOAP or sending a query string, but not with JSON.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to give your input to the `data` property as a JSON string, not as an object:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:63056/Service1.asmx/PrintOrderRecieptXml",
    data: '{"CouponCode":"TESTCODE","Subtotal":14.2600,"ShippingTotal":7.5000,"TaxTotal":0.0000,"GrandTotal":21.7600,"OrderItemCollection":[{"Total":14.2600,"Qty":250}]}',
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    error: function(xhr, msg) {
      alert(xhr.statusText);
    }
  });
});
```

[Using jQuery to Consume ASP.NET JSON Web Services](http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/) has a good explanation of the requirements when talking to ASP.Net Web Services.

Comment: That seems to be the right path. However, still doesn't work in firefox. Works great in IE.

Comment: How does it fail in Firefox now?  Do you see the request at the server?  Does the request get processed properly by ASP.Net?  Is it hitting your `error` handler client-side?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, the response returns to the success function of the ajax call but the response object itself is always null in Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

Douglas is correct - you need to format the data as a string.  Be sure to read all of the posts on the blog that he linked you to.  Encosia is a great resource for Ajax and Asp.Net.

Answer (score 1):

asp.net webservices don't return json normally. take a look here:
[JSON WebService in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325081/json-webservice-in-asp-net)